# i cant access the str obj in below statement to connect.why?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
string str  = "server= xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog= hgjhg;User Id=root;Password= jhgjhg@123"; 
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
```

I can't access the str obj in below statement to connect, why?

Comment: Dont share the ip address here. just give some junk ip address.

Comment: @VenkataramanR I removed it for them.

Comment: @YannickMeeus Thanks

Comment: Yeah, can't do anything about that, I'm afraid :(

Comment: You have to pass the connectionstring to the constructor. MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(str);

Comment: *"I can't access the str obj"* - What do you even mean by that?  What specifically are you trying and what specific problem are youn encountering?  "I can't" isn't a description of an error.

Comment: @YannickMeeus ::  Thank You..I just forget to delete it.

Comment: @VenkataramanR:  i tried to pass MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(str); but i cant access str in this string?

Comment: If there is accessibility issue, try to initialize str as a readonly member of class outside of function, assign str with connString in constructor and use it any where in the class.

Comment: @Kochu: *"but i cant access str in this string?"* - Again, what do you even *mean* by that?  What's the *actual problem*?

Comment: What is the actual error message you are getting when you use `MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(str);`?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [MySqlConnection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html) the examples show that you need to pass the connection string to the constructor:

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
```